# jQuery datatable - fnReloadAjax does not override sAjaxSource

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have the following code which shows all rows by default and when clicking the .view-unread-rows button the datatable should only show unread rows.  However, it does not appear to be running the reload query.

```
$(".view-unread-rows").click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    message_table.fnReloadAjax("/letters/ajax/T");
    message_table.fnDraw();
});

$(".view-all-rows").click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    message_table.fnReloadAjax("/letters/ajax/F");
    message_table.fnDraw();
});

message_table = $('.message_table').dataTable({
    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "iDisplayStart": 0,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sServerMethod": "POST",
    "sAjaxSource": "/letters/ajax/F",
    "sDom": '<"top">rt<"bottom"><"clear">',
    "aaSorting": [[3, 'desc']],
    "aoColumns": [          
            { "bSortable": false },
            { "bSortable": true },
            { "bSortable": false },
            { "bSortable": true }
    ],
    "oLanguage": {
        "sEmptyTable": "No results"
    }
});
```

I have had this working but I've changed something at some point and it's now stopped. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

OK, oddly enough, this seems to work fine if there are no results for clicking on `.view-unread-rows`.

Still no clue though.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).on('click', '.view-unread-rows', function(e) { ...
```